# How to SELECT and get COUNT for all in the same query?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I have a query that is assembled like so (using a Django backend):

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE'
if condition1:
    sql += ' `col1` = "foo" OR'

if condition2:
    sql += ' `col2` = "bar" OR'
...

if conditionN:
    sql += ' `colN` = "foobar" OR'

sql = sql[:-2] //to remove the extra 'OR'

sql += 'ORDER BY `col1` LIMIT x OFFSET y'

print(sql) //'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `col1` = "foo" OR `col2` = "bar" ... OR `colN` == "foobar" ORDER BY `col1` LIMIT x OFFSET y'
```

> I need a query to fetch a `COUNT(*)` for **all** rows in `table`, but still `SELECT` from the database with the conditions and `LIMIT` from above

I tried doing something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, IFNULL(COUNT(t2.*), 0) AS childCount 
FROM `table` AS t1 LEFT JOIN `table` AS t2
WHERE `col1` = "foo" OR `col2` = 'bar' OR `colN` = 'foobar' 
ORDER BY `col1` desc LIMIT 10;
```

If you couldn't already tell, I'm utterly confused about whats happening in the query above and it doesn't work (obviously).

### Update

The table looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+
|  col1  |   col2   | 
+--------+----------+
|   a    |   foo    |      
|   b    |   foo    |      
|   c    |   bar    |      
|   d    |   bar    |     
|   e    |   foo    | 
+--------+----------+
```

example query I need:

```
'SELECT *, COUNT(*) as childCount FROM `table` WHERE `col2` = "foo" LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0'
```

It needs to return this:

```
("a", "foo") //because of the 'LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0' 
childCount = 3 //because there is 3 columns 'WHERE `col2` = "foo"'
```

Suggestions/Explanations would really be appreciated :)

Comment: can you provide in plain english what your desired output would be, the code you provided makes little to no sense and the sql snippet you provided below it is not valid sql to begin with

Comment: You need a separate (or sub) query.

Comment: If this is django, why are you using raw query instead of django query api?

Comment: they might not have set up ORM @daniherrera

Comment: @aws_apprentice I need a query to have the conditions of the first snippet (LIMIT x, OFFSET y, etc) and fetch the `COUNT` of the first snippet **without** `LIMIT x`

Comment: You need 2 queries. Easier using django's orm.

Comment: @Jane sorry that still doesn't make much sense to me. Can you please use pseudo code and edit the post

Comment: @dani herrera  Are you *sure* that it Isn't possible with 1 query?

Comment: @ aws_apprentice sure working on an edit now

Comment: @Jane, are you using django ORM ? Or raw queries? And why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated question

you can

```
select col1,col2,count from (
select col2,count(col2) as count from table1 group by col2 order by col1)a
order by col1
limit 1
offset 0
```

Comment: I tried this but got `Error Code: 1064 near " *) over()" at line 1`.  I assume this is because I'm using mysql and not PostgreSQL, but I'm not sure how to convert it to the proper syntax.

Comment: Mysql earlier versions used to not support window functions. see edit @Jane

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, b.childCount
FROM table a
JOIN (
  SELECT c.col2, COUNT(1)
  FROM table c
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 2 DESC) b
ON a.col2 = b.col2
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 0
```